# Is the word 'restrictionable' correct?

Tags: word-meaning, suffixes, morphology

How do you form -able words? Which root do you have to attach the suffix to in order to make the new word?

For example, is the word 'restrictionable' correct?

*restriction* + *-able* ⇒ 'that may or should be restricted'?

Comment: Did you even googled this word? If you did, you would have known then.

Comment: Yes , I googled it. I didn't find any results. But if the word billable is formed from bill + able I thought that maybe my word was correct. If it isn't correct can you tell me the correct word that I am looking for? Thanks

Comment: you can easily find the word "billable" online and in dictionaries. But one can not create new words on their own. What is the word you want for?

Comment: you can use "hyphen" probably. ***Restriction-able.***

Comment: Why wouldn't you use restrictable? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/restrictable

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "is this a real word" can be answered with a dictionary. If it is a request for a word that has a specific meaning, the question should be rephrased.

Comment: Thanks @CollenV. I think this is the word I am looking for.

Comment: @ColleenV But many suffixes in English are *productive* which means they can be used to form words that have never been said before. I don't know for sure whether this is one of them. It seems to me that in a situation where official restrictions were regularly placed on things according to various criteria, we could use a word like this. It wouldn't mean the same thing as *restrictable*, it seems to me.

Comment: @ColleenV ... *but*, the biggest problem with that would be that this suffix is normally used to make adjectives from verbs, not from nouns (although there are exceptions). So this would probably be an impediment to the felicitous creation of the word. So the big point here is about how this particular suffix can be used. There's no limit, it seems to me, on using this suffix with transitive *verbs*. So it would seem to be a valid grammar question.

Comment: Google solves this fast... put on hold.

Comment: @Araucaria I'm not arguing a point. I'm asking a question to the asker to try to understand their thinking. I think this could be worked into a good question, but I would like to understand the OP's purpose better instead of just imposing what I think the question should be.

Comment: I filed the hold vote because of "no research" and "can easily be solved with a Google search"... which is filed in "not learning English - off-topic"... I have no idea why "no research" is considered "off-topic".

Comment: Oh, but it's such an interesting question, and so hard to answer!  Certainly a simple search on Google would be insufficient.  Most dictionaries have entries for *-able* (e.g. [the ODE](http://goo.gl/7cLlFu)), but they don't really explain the rules for *-able* affixation. How is a learner to know that *desirable* is okay but *wantable* is generally not? They have access to positive evidence but not negative.  I feel like questions about affixation should be considered as on-topic as any other sort of grammar question. That's why I voted to reopen.

Comment: Then the question should be changed to a general question about the suffix, instead of a specific case of "is this a real word" (which I was referring to as easily googleable).

Comment: @Araucaria: For what it's worth, [the use of "Off-Topic" for all custom close reasons is an artifact of the software, and can't presently be avoided](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210314/categories-other-than-off-topic-should-allow-custom-close-reasons).

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the annoying things about SE. BTW, I'm trying to fix the question.

Comment: I put an edit in review queue.

Comment: @Nihilist Another annoying thing is long comment threads. Please refrain from adding not comments as comments.

Comment: Sometimes I don't realize when comments become uneditable, that's why I messed it up. May as well do Ctrl+C+V, delete and repost next time.

Answer (score 4):

We can freely make new adjectives from verbs using the suffix *-able*. It does not matter at all whether these words have ever been used before. It does not matter if these words are in the dictionary or not. Anybody can understand these words as long as they understand the verb involved. When we can use a suffix like this, we call it a *productive* suffix. We can have productive prefixes too.

The suffix *-able* is a productive suffix. We use it to turn verbs into adjectives. However, there are a few restrictions:

- We can't freely do this with intransitive verbs, unless they have some kind of preposition phrase following.
- If there is already an adjective ending in the suffix *-ible*, then you can't usually spell it with *-able*. There aren't many words like this. One example is *accessible*. If you write *accessable* then your spell-checker or your teacher will mark it as wrong.

So think of any transitive verb you like, stick an *-able* on the end of it, and you'll almost definitely have a nice, perfectly formed adjective:

- *askable, thinkable, swimmable, runnable, openable, finishable, restrictable, swallowable, spendable, meetable,*

**The Original Poster's example**

We can definitely use the word restrictable. The problem with the word *restrictionable* is that the base word, *restriction*, is a noun, not a verb. For this reason the adjective *restrictionable* will probably not work for the OP's needs.

However, if some company or other uses the word *restriction* like a verb as part of their jargon, then they could also freely use the word *restrictionable* as an adjective too!

Answer (score 4):

*-Able*/*-ible* goes on the ends of verbs, not nouns.  Many words in English work as both verbs and nouns.  However, if the *-ion* suffix on a word was used to turn a word into a noun, awkwardness can happen.

But really English with its grammar lets you use any word in many parts of speech even if they are not "supposed" to be used in such a way.  Some words not commonly used in this way will sound weird, but it'd be rare for it to sound so weird that someone couldn't figure out what you meant.

*Restrict* is a verb.  *Restrict-ion* is a noun-ified version of *restrict* meaning *instance or event of being restricted* or *something that causes or maintains a state of being restricted*.

So, can you use *restriction* as a verb?  It's not common, but possible.  The meaning won't substitute exactly for *restrict*.

Here's a contrived example that may not ever had been said at someone in reality, but I could image it happening:

> A: I think Jon over there is on restriction and  can't do the task.
>
> B: Who restrictioned him?
>
> A: His boss, well, really his doctor.
>
> B: Ok, find me someone who's not on restriction and get it done.

Here, *restrictioned* means *placed on restriction* - and if it sounds/feels like a made-up word, it is, but it does follow the rules.  Furthermore notice the above is a workplace/business setting where this type of thing might happen more often than not.  Anyway, *on restriction* here means he is marked in some system or list as being restricted from a task - but *restrict* means *prevent from doing something*.

So to answer your question, *-able*/*-ible* is put on the same form of a *verb* that you'd use for the infinitive.

Answer (score 2):

In informal English, you can coin masses of new words where they won't have a formal definition, but your readers/listeners will know instinctively what you mean.

I know that by **restrictionable** - you mean "is able to be restricted".

Particularly with the suffix **-able**, we can append this to just about any word to mean "able to do ..", and you'll find native speakers often do! We usually keep the hyphen in place for words that we know aren't "real" words.

> Most words, particularly verbs are suffix-able with -able.
>   We set up the tent on the most camp-able ground we could find, but it was still a bit uncomfortable.
>   My friend is so embarrass-able. Just one mention of his school nickname turned him bright pink.